# Installing tkinter on PyCharm/Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

So I have been trying lots of things and googled for this (many answers to this question on stackoverflow, but none worked for me). Basically I have PyCharm on Windows. I have a python project using python 3.8 (virtualenv). I'm trying to use 'tkinter' in this project but this import fails:

```
import tkinter
```

[image]

So I try the suggestion of installing future package. That seems to work (no errors). I restart PyCharm but after that the error simply remains. I also tried to manually install 'tkinter' package. So I look in 'Available Packages' and search for 'tkinter'. I see lots of packages starting with 'tkinter' (like 'tkinter-nav', 'tkinter-math', ...) but no 'tkinter'. Installing any of these other tkinter packages doesn't help.

So I'm a bit stuck now. I'm using Windows 10 btw.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Surprising enough, `tkinter` is supposed to be preinstalled

Comment: yes, but why do I get that error then? ('No module named tkinter')

Comment: Can you import `tkinter` in normal `Python` 3.8 environment (not inside `virtualenv`)?

Comment: PyCharm is a very complex editor, and a much as it may seem like a good beginner tool, it is actually pretty terrible for beginners. It holds your hand too much, but also not enough. You need to learn python AND PyCharm. I would suggest throwing PyCharm in the garbage, getting a simple editor, and go follow some tutorial on how to create your own virtualenv.

Comment: I'm actually pretty good with python. Have been programming in it for more then a decade now. I can go back to doing this with vim but would prefer to get it working in a more comfortable editor first. I'll do some experiments

Comment: Just tried with a real python install and that didn't help either

Comment: @McJty ~ I didn't actually mean that YOU personally needed to learn python. I just meant that an editor like PyCharm just complicates things. I used it for about a month when I first started, and whereas I didn't have any problems, I always felt like my code was in prison. You'll see what I mean when you get it working.

Comment: Then you forgot to include `tkinter` when installing Python.  Reinstall Python and make sure include `tkinter`.

Comment: Hmm indeed. Reinstalling python fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `import tkinter as tk` or `from tkinter import *` normally more compatible & workable with more addons; or at least to my experience

Answer (score 0):

"import tkinter" can be employed as long as you the word tkinter is used when creating your objects, such as:

```
var = tkinter.StringVar()
username_box = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=var, font=("Arial", 14))
username_box.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html